# Entity Framework says foreign key doesnt exists, but it does

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to run an Entity Framework (v6.1.3) migration update with the code below:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable') " +
        "ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable");
}
```

but it keeps throwing the error below when I run the `update-database` command:

> 'FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

If I run the SQL in SQL Server Management Studio, no errors are shown, and the foreign key is dropped.

**Edit**: just tested this code below and it works as well. What's the difference?

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable", "FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable");
}
```

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable`

Comment: You could be write a incorrect table name or fk name

Comment: Can you check what is the final string which is getting created may be you need to include some spaces.

Comment: @IgorQuirino That's a terrible edit that you have suggested, it removes a key tag (Entity Framework) which is integral to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted SQL Express and VS2015 and that seemed to clear the issue.